# Swap first with Last

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have to code a program in which a user input some number and the program have to swap the first digit form last number.

For Example user inputs: `12345`
The expected output would then be: `52341`
But I am getting an error and getting output like: `4465`

This is my Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void main()
{ int num,ln,fn,pw,dg,swap;
    cin >> num;
    ln = num%10 ;
    dg = log10(num);
    pw = pow(10,dg);
    fn = num%pw;
    swap = ln*pw;
    swap = swap+num/pw;
    swap = swap-ln;
    swap = swap+fn;
    cout << swap << endl;
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: Post your code as text, not image please.

Comment: I try to post my code as text but getting an unknown errors that’s why i post as image.

Comment: Then you better fix the error, nobody is going to waste time converting your image back to text.

Comment: Just a minute i will again try to post my code as text.

Comment: @john  Thanks to edit my Question and add code.

Comment: @Slava and P i, The Question is edited and Code is added in Question by John can you please help me now to solve this.

Comment: BTW, you may loose some accuracy when converting from integer to floating point and back, using the `pow` function.  The `pow` function uses floating point and returns floating point.

Comment: There's an error in your math, you add the quantity `num%pw` twice to your result (one time as `fn` and one time as `num%pw`). Plus you have the problem of rounding errors. Basically you are doing it the wrong way. Instead of trying to do complicated mathematics, you should regard the number as a sequence of digits and convert it to a string. manipulate the digits in the string and then convert back to a number as YSC explains below.

Comment: @John The quantity error you told me doesn't solve my problem and i have to complete this task using math function, and not by using  string YSC answer is helpful but i have to complete this task using math function.

Comment: @SyedKomailHassan Have a look now, I've posted a working version.

Comment: @john  Thank you very much!

Comment: OP, why are you accepting/unaccepting my answer? This is the second time now.

Answer (score 4):

> Help me to solve this.

Ok I'll do it.

#### 0. Design choice(s)

The operation you want to do is not on the *value* of the input number but rather on its *representation*, specifically in base 10. We'd better go for a string manipulation then.

#### 1. Integer to string

With C++11 and following, we do have [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string): takes an integer, returns a string, done.

#### 2. Accessing characters from a string

If the string is not empty, [`std::string::front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front) and [`std::string::back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) return a reference to the first and last characters of that string, easy.

#### 3. Swapping characters

We have the utility [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) and the swap idiom

```
using std::swap;
swap(lhs, rhs);
```

`lhs` and `rhs` being what needs to be swapped (see step 2.).

#### 4. Back to integer

We have [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) doing what `std::to_string` does but in reverse, done. But what if the new integer has become *too big* to be held by an integer type?

#### 5. Putting all together

Let's define a (free) function!

```
int reverse_border_digits(int value)
{
    // steps 1 through 4
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of my choice of word... any suggestion to replace _Extracting_?

Comment: agree, they are not really extracted. Why not "Accessing" ? My favourite part of the answer `//steps 1 through 4` :)

Comment: @user463035818 perfect :)

Comment: As for point 0, note that this *can* be done numerically by computing a number of the form a99...9b where a and b are digits and the total number of digits is the same as the number to mutate. `b` is the difference between the first and last digit, and `a` similarly offset by 1.

Comment: Yes numerical manipulation is an option but, in my opinion, string manipulation is easier, makes for simpler code, is less error-prone. @Bathsheba Quoting myself: _"We'd better go for a string manipulation"_: I never said this is the only option! Also note that at the time I wrote this answer, OP had not provided code yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer fulfilling the OP requirements

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    int dg = (int)(log10(num + 0.000001)); // add small delta to avoid any possible rounding error on an exact power of ten
    int pw = (int)round(pow(10.0, dg));
    int swap = (num % 10) * pw + (num - num % 10 - (num / pw) * pw) + num / pw;
    cout << swap << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Lovely (upped), although I'd rather see `round(log10(num))`; I dislike magic numbers. Or perhaps even roll your own digit counter. Also, you ought to round `pow` too (although I'd calculate that at the same time as I calculate the number of digits).

Comment: Yes, `round` is obviously the best way to do it.

Comment: Do roll back my edit if you don't like it. Personally I'd write `num / pw * pw` as it's idiomatic.

Comment: Actually I was being so naughty I trolled the answer. Rolled back, with apologies.

Comment: @Bathsheba remember when I said this method is error-prone? Well [john's implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7beb2e436bd5754e) is wrong even though he is an experienced C++ programmer and you reviewed his code. Please don't write that type of code unless you really have to ;)

Comment: @YSC You got me, My original version was better before I removed the 'magic number' and used `round` instead. I've put it back to the earlier version, hopefully not to late for the OP. And I completey agree conversion to a string is the simple and obvious way to do this. I only posted the above because the OP said he had to do it mathematically.